# A typical credit card company charges 18% annual interest, compounded monthly...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*A typical credit card company charges 18% annual interest, compounded monthly, on the unpaid balance. If your current balance is $520 and you do not make any payments for 6 months, how much will you owe?*

The first step I did was to plug in values in the compound interest formula:

> $$\begin{align}
> A &= P(1+r/n)^{n\cdot t} \\
> A &= 520(1+.18/12)^{12\cdot 6} \\
> A &= 1519.00
> \end{align}$$

I have done these steps, but the correct answer is $A=568.59$, I believe. How do I find this correct answer?

Comment: You want $t=\frac12$, since you want the interest for one-half of a year.  Your calculation gives the balance if no payments are made for $6$ years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compound it $6$ times
$$520*\left(1+\frac{0.18}{12}\right)^6$$